# Why is the current generation more interested in quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, special-relativity

Earlier people used to be obsessed with thermodynamics and laws describing behavior of gases, electric current, gravity. Cavendish,Kelvin, Newton and etc etc etc. But now in every movie, I see physics as being referred to as parallel worlds, alternate reality blah blah which has perhaps created this interest. Will they ever realize that quantum physics is not just parallel worlds to justify Spiderman. This is actually sad because it gives them a wrong perception or a sort of delusion about quantum physics. Physics S.E most popular site --Quantum Physics. I don't wan't to be rude but just need to know your opinion;)

Comment: *just need to know your opinion* Opinion-based questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Which site should I move it to?

Comment: try the physics subreddit

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the current generation more interested in quantum physics?

I can answer this for physicists.

The classical theories were formulated  and were able to describe the data up to a certain accuracy. By the end of the 19th century the beginning of the 20th there were data that could not be fitted with the classical theories, mechanics, thermodynamics , classical electromagnetism.

These were the [black body radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html), [the photoelectric effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html), and the [spectra of the atoms](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html) .

Quantum mechanics slowly evolved from various proposals to solve these problems, to finally become a theory which is accepted as **the underlying framework of all other theories** which are emergent from it (excluding special and general relativity which are an extra page).

Unfortunately popularization of quantum mechanical concepts has led to a lot of noise, most of it inaccurate and misleading.One has to study the mathematics of the theory to be able to grasp it.

Comment: Funny approach. Did you know the question was going to be closed, so prepared a placeholder?

Comment: @Ruslan yes , I could guess, it has happened to me often enough

Comment: @Ruslan I have found that moderators can be very fast in closing iffy questions,  often while I am in the  middle of writing an answer. I answer iffy questions, in order  to put in links that could educate the questioner, and also be useful for search engines.

Comment: @Ruslan   This giving of links can be done in a comment, but comments also have a way of disappearing without notice. So I have found the placeholder method in order not to waste the time I spend in framing an answer.